# plot contour of mesh data in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, contour

I have some data to plot in 2D contour mode with matlab and it seems to be a little tricky to plot. I have a 2D unstructured triangular mesh with x and y coordinates of centers of triangles and and lets say velocity and these centers of triangle;

```
x(:)=[x(1), x(2), ..., x(N)] 
y(:)=[y(1), y(2), ..., y(N)] 
u(:)=[u(1), u(2), ..., u(N)]
```

The first picture below is the original meshgrid with the coordinates of vertices rather than the coordinates of centers of cells which what I want to use[original mesh using vertices coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqS7m.png)

And with my try using Delaunay triangulation, I obtained this meshgrid
[meshgrid I obtained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVe2v.jpg)

clearly, It's very different and at the boundary is badly triangulated [boundary problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPRb0.png) and also [boundary problem 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EiPC.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use `griddata` to create a surface
Use `contour` to create contours

Comment: The domain is convex. I tried the delaunay method and used griddata, indeed. But it appears that the results are biased as long a it is an interpolation. is there any way to keep the exact values and plot them without interpolate?

Comment: Can you attach the data? Is there a chance to interpolate in spherical system?

Comment: I don't understand. What is wrong about `griddata`? DOesn't it work?